# my-appname| /bin/sh: 1: /app/tmpmain.exe: not found | air

Tags: docker, go, air

I'm facing an issue, am trying to run my go fiber project inside docker with `air` but am getting this error
`uni-blog  | /bin/sh: 1: /app/tmpmain.exe: not found`

am using
Windows 11
Docker desktop
golang latest
air  1.27.10
fiber latest

Here is my docker compose and dockerfile

```
# docker-compose up -d --build
version: "3.8"

services:
  app:
    container_name: uni-blog
    image: app-dev
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

```
FROM golang:1.17 as development

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y && \
  apt install -y git \
  make openssh-client

RUN curl -fLo install.sh https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cosmtrek/air/master/install.sh \
    && chmod +x install.sh && sh install.sh && cp ./bin/air /bin/air

RUN air -v

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod go.sum ./

RUN go mod download

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD air
```

I also tried installing air following the readME instructions still it gives me this error
Please help

Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please ask the author of fiber.

Comment: I tried running this but i get error that directory is incorrect  ``` docker run -it --rm \
 -w "/github.com/raliqala/uni-blog" \
 -v $(pwd):/github.com/raliqala/uni-blog \
 -p 3000:3000 \
 uni-blog/app
docker: Error response from daemon: the working directory 'C:/Program Files/Git/github.com/raliqala/uni-blog' is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path.
See 'docker run --help'.```  so i tried air init still nothing

Comment: It works well locally but it does not work in docker

Answer (score 1):

The `volumes:` mount you have replaces the `/app` directory in the image with content from the host.  If the binary is built in the Dockerfile, that `volumes:` mount hides it; if you don't have a matching compatible binary on the host in the same place, you'll get an error like what you see.

I'd remove that `volumes:` block so you're actually running the binary that's built into the image.  The `docker-compose.yml` file can be reduced to as little as:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
```

Comment: This answer helped but am still experiencing the air error although when I build without air, and build my app.go it works now

Answer (score 1):

If you look the error, you ca notice there is a typo between tmp/main.exe:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /app/tmpmain.exe: not found
```

This is coming from .air.toml config file:

```
    bin = "tmp\\main.exe"
```

Create .air.toml file in project root like so:

```
root = "."
tmp_dir = "tmp"

[build]

  # Build binary.
  cmd = "go build -o ./tmp/main.exe ."

  # Read binary.
  bin = "tmp/main.exe"

  # Watch changes in those files
  include_ext = [ "go", "yml"]

  # Ignore changes in these files
  exclude_dir = ["tmp"]

  # Stop builds from triggering too fast
  delay = 1000 # ms

[misc]
  clean_on_exit = true
```